# My public website name and AD domain name are the same. How can I get to my external website from inside my network?

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, domain

I am using my domain `example.org`in my firm. I can use `www.example.org`to view my website. If I try `http://example.org` from outsite my firm there is no problem, but if I try it from inside, my windows DNS servers deliverthe IPs of domain controllers.

How can I solve this? Can I prevent my DCs from registering as `example.org` in my DNS and will this be a problem for my enviroment?

Comment: To clarify, your internal network DNS name is example.org, and not something like example.local?

Comment: You can solve this by naming your domain correctly, it should be something like `ad.example.org`, or `corp.example.org`. If that's no longer possible you're stuck. The best you can do is setup a redirect to `www.example.org` on any DCs that also have IIS installed (a bad idea, but a lot of domain controllers are setup poorly).

Comment: "Can I prevent my DCs from registering as example.org in my DNS" - nope. "and will this be a problem for my enviroment?" - YES!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you've named your Active Directory `example.org` then you cannot prevent this. You've gone against Microsft's best practices for naming an AD and you're seeing one of the symptoms.

You have a few choices:

1. Migrate to a properly named AD. Something like `corp.example.org`.
2. Install a web server on each DC and configure it to forward web requests for `example.org` to `www.example.org`. This is dirty and shouldn't be done, but it's an option nonetheless.
3. Train your users to go to `www.example.org` internally.

I've blogged about AD naming best practices multiple times and link to official Microsoft sources. You should read them:

- http://web.archive.org/web/20200214122247/http://www.mdmarra.com/2013/04/best-practices-for-configuring-new.html
- http://web.archive.org/web/20191201074255/www.mdmarra.com/2012/11/why-you-shouldnt-use-local-in-your.html
- http://web.archive.org/web/20200122002118/www.mdmarra.com/2013/07/more-documentation-from-microsoft-about.html

If you want the short version:

> Do not create new Active Directory forests with the same name as an
> external DNS name. For example, if your Internet DNS URL is
> http://contoso.com, you must choose a different name for your internal
> forest to avoid future compatibility issues. That name should be
> unique and unlikely for web traffic. For example: corp.contoso.com.

-http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574166.aspx

Comment: In addition, you can setup a simple "example" CNAME in DNS (example.example.org technically) and have it point to www.example.org.  Then you can just tell users to go to `http://example`.  Silly of course, otherwise #3 in MDMarra's list is the only simple solution to the issue.  I've been there (split-dns) and it isn't fun to deal with.

Comment: As long as "example" isn't the NetBIOS name for your domain. If it is, I can imagine what merry hell this would play in such an environment.

Comment: I will get me some information about migration to a properly name, I am just a little bit afraid of getting problems through it. The problem is with my Nagios Monitoring which I use to make sure that `www.example.org` and `example.org` is fine from external. Here i will go and find an alternative for my setup as long i have/will not migrate. Thx

Comment: I just want to update the answer... while it was once the best practice recommendation by Microsoft, RFC supercedes it, as it interferes with zeroconf (mDNS). Also, this [TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc726016%28v=ws.10%29.aspx/) recommends against it (as of 2012), especially if you are looking to integrate your AD environment with Office 365 or using Macs on your domain, as we have both happening where I work. One noted workaround would be to use a split zone, as [detailed here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/4d97325b-ff3a-4f46-b

Comment: @stevenh read the article you linked to again. It echoes my answer completely. When moving to office 365 with a hybrid identity you should set the user principal name to match the primary SMTP address of each user. This is completely independent of your directory's name. My answer was valid when I posted it and it is still valid today.

Answer (score 6):

If you are running Exchange on the DC, do not set up a PortProxy - it may go without saying but it will break Exchange services hosted on port 80.

I realize this post is quite old, but you can still do this without installing IIS on the DC's. On every DC, run the following command to portproxy port 80 to the external web server.

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=80 listenaddress={Static IP v4 address of DC) connectport=80 connectaddress={IP Address of public Web Server}
```

Comment: this requires the webserver to be reachable from the DC. But non the less a nice way. Then you could redirect to www. version to take the work from the DC. (Pro tipp: i think portproxy needs "ip helper" service of windows)

Answer (score 0):

So, I don't know if this evaded anyone else, but the best fix for this issue may just be getting a secondary domain with a different suffix, especially if you cannot PortProxy because of Exchange being on the DC(or because of hostheaders issues with your web host.)

ex:  If the internal AD Domain is **EXAMPLE.com** - then you should simply purchase **EXAMPLE.NET** for internal use.

This is the cheapest and simplest workaround for internal web access.

That worked for us.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the URL as a domain, use machine names such as dc1.example.com and dc2.example.com for each server

make sure the CNAME is setup for each server properly for the proper server IP address

I have been able to do this by making a CNAME first then setup the servers, wait a day for the DNS records to propogate

Answer (score 0):

You can create new host (A or AAAA) in DNS Setting and set the IP of website to it.
for example in internal network go to website by www2.example.org address instead of [www.example.org](http://www.example.org).

Answer (score -2):

You may solve your problem two ways, but it involves placing an HTTP server on your DCs :

You can do the redirection with an URL redirect (HTTP 301 code), IIS 7 can do that for you, or you can install a reverse proxy (Apache for Windows) and use the following code :

> ProxyPass / http://www.example.com/
>
> ProxyPassRever / http://www.example.com/
>
> ProxyPreserveHost On

Comment: This is included in MDMarra's answer; it's item 2.