# Preventing domain controller from adding A/AAAA for domain root

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I have set up the domain `contoso.com`. The domain controllers in the domain are also the DNS servers within the network.

When users try to resolve `contoso.com`, they receive the A/AAAA records of the domain controllers. However, we want `contoso.com` to resolve to a different address (the web server of the company).

We added the A/AAAA records for the web server to the domain root, but noticed that there were additional A/AAAA records, pointing to the domain controllers. We removed those, but they are being re-created.

How do I prevent this from happening? I did not notice any degraded performance or other issues while the records were not present.

Comment: You didn't use your DNS domain name `contoso.com` as the [name of your AD domain](http://serverfault.com/a/76721/37681) did you?

Comment: @HBruijn That is exactly what I did. My previous thought was that you're not supposed to do it, but I never really knew *why*

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/526213/37681 is also of interest